# Python sleep if a function runs for 20 times

Tags: python, django, time, celery, sleep

I have a function for sending an email which is used in a celery task i need to make the code sleep for a second if that email function is ran for 20 times how can i make this happpen.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def send_email_reminder_due_date(self):
     send_email_from_template(
        subject_template_path='emails/0.txt',
        body_template_path='emails/1.html',
        template_data=template_data,
        to_email_list=email_list,
        fail_silently=False,
        content_subtype='html'
    )
```

so the above code is celery periodic task which runs daily i filter the todays date and send the email for all the records which are today's date if the number of records is more than 20 lets say so for evry 20 emails sent we need to make the code sleep for a second

**send_email_from_template is function which is used for sending an email**

Comment: is this running on single server or multi node cluster? easy to do if on single machine, might need to bring in central cache or IMDG to deal on multi node.

Comment: @NoobEditor Can u post the answer for single server

Comment: Why don't you just sleep for 0.1 seconds every time?

Comment: @TimRoberts That's what required to do so no chance

Comment: @jimmy ljdyer answer pretty much does the job

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing a vital point here around what you can/can't do because you are using celery, but I'll post in case it's useful. You can track function state by assigning attributes to functions. In the below code I assign an attribute `times_without_sleep` to a dummy function and track its value to sleep every 20 calls.

```
# ====================
def my_function():

    if not hasattr(my_function, 'times_without_sleep'):
        my_function.times_without_sleep = 0

    print('Do the stuff')

    if my_function.times_without_sleep >= 20:
        print('Sleep')
        my_function.times_without_sleep = 0
    else:
        my_function.times_without_sleep += 1


# ====================
if __name__ == "__main__":

    for i in range(0, 100):
        my_function()
```

You can also set the attribute value for the function if you need to set e.g. `my_function.times_without_sleep = 0` at the end of round of emails etc.

Couldn't you just do something like this with `send_email_from_template`? You can also make it a decorator as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72930481/sleep-decorator-after-n-function-calls-python-selenium) to avoid cluttering the function code.